# continue parsing after reading ugly character

Tags: c, libxml2

i have a XML-response (supposed to be UTF-8 by encoding-attribute), that contains inside as an element a character "\uffff\u0551", for which `xmlParseMemory()` results a NULL-Document with error `XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt` [not wellformed].

can I setup the parserChain, so that the library will skip these characters and continue parsing with a result-Document?

I did read some (not every) manual pages from xmlsoft.org, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  FFFF is not a [valid Unicode character](http://unicode.org/charts), invalid characters are fatal errors, and the XML spec declares [fatal errors are unrecoverable](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-terminology):

> Once a fatal error is detected, however, the processor must not continue normal processing (i.e., it must not continue to pass character data and information about the document's logical structure to the application in the normal way).

If you want to parse this document, you'll need to clean out the invalid characters before handing it to an XML parser.

Comment: what a pity. I hoped for some "magic" inside the libxml2 that does this clean up. (as I do not know, what more invalids the opposite site is sending me in the future)

Comment: It does suck for this specific situation.  XML was designed with these rigors on the spec so we can declare, "this site is producing invalid XML."  Because we're guaranteed no parser can handle it directly, it hopefully puts pressure on them to fix their broken software.